# jsdoc: extend type with template (extend type with generic)

Tags: webstorm, jsdoc

Example:

Base type:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} LabelValue
 * @template T
 * @property {String} label
 * @property {T} value
 */
```

Could be used fine as

`/** @type {LabelValue<SomeType>} */`

I want to extend this base type like this (maybe this is just wrong syntax, I don't know for sure):

```
/**
 * @typedef {LabelValue<T>} LabelValueExtended
 * @template T
 * @property {String} extensionProp
 */
```

I use webstorm and it doesn't show me any suggestions based on type used like this:

`/** @type {LabelValueExtended<SomeType>} */`

This variant also doesn't trigger any suggestion from webstorm:

```
/**
 * @typedef {LabelValue} LabelValueExtended
 * @template T
 * @property {String} label
 * @property {T} value
 * @property {String} extensionProp
 */
```

But only if I replace my custom type with common type like `Object` templates work fine. E.g. this works:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} LabelValueExtended
 * @template T
 * @property {String} label
 * @property {T} value
 * @property {String} extensionProp
 */
```

And my first example of Base type also works fine because it extends common `Object` type. But if I do something dummy e.g.

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Dummy
 * @property {String} dummy
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Dummy} LabelValue
 * @template T
 * @property {String} label
 * @property {T} value
 */
```

It also breaks any property suggestions from webstorm.

Types without templates work fine. E.g.

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Dummy
 * @property {String} dummy
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Dummy} LabelValue
 * @property {String} label
 * @property {*} value
 */
```

If used like this: `/** @type {LabelValue} */`, then webstorm suggests correctly props from both types, but obviously I won't get any suggestions for `value` property.

The question is: am I use incorrect syntax for jsdoc with templates (please suggest the valid one) or webstorm just handles it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I use rider (another product of JetBrains, same as WebStrom)
For me the best thing that worked was like this: (Although it is not fully without fault, so please read to the end)

```js
/**
 * @typedef LabelValueExtended
 * @extends {LabelValue<T>}
 * @template T
 */
```

although my case was more like this:

```js
/**
 * @typedef module:invoice.PurchaseOrderWithInvoicePaymentTermItemsResponseDto
 * @extends {BaseInvoiceWithInvoicePaymentTermItemsResponseDto<module:invoice.PurchaseOrderResponse>}
 */
```

After defining (*The Cons and Pros are mentioned in the comments*)

```js
/** @type {module:invoice.PurchaseOrderWithInvoicePaymentTermItemsResponseDto} */
var x={};
// [Keyboard combination based on Resharper key map]
x. // [Ctrl+Space] Here I get no suggestion from IDE
x. // [Ctrl+Q] it doesn't give me direct suggestion either
// invoice is defined in `BaseInvoiceWithInvoicePaymentTermItemsResponseDto`, and it is generic of type `PurchaseOrderResponse`
x.invoice //it just points to the base type, not the derived type
x.invoice //[Ctrl+Q] HERE it gives me the derived type | it means my mapping work, but its rider unable to render it properly in other places
```

### **regarding the comments**

Image 1:

1. it knows the base type
2. it's unable to list the property, as it list contents of a known type
3. it's unable to load the correct derived type

[image: 2022-Rider JSDoc Extended Type usage, properties listing]
Image 2:

1. It still didn't detect the class, it's just the indexing that tell it exists in some places

[image: 2022-Rider JSDoc Extended Type usage, on specific property outside object]

Image 3:

1. it can bring the right description for the property type if you use documentation dialog (for resharper key-map Ctrl+Q), and define the property inside the referenced object (without specifying the type again)

[image: 2022-Rider JSDoc Extended Type usage, on specific property inside object]

Image 4:

1. After defining the property inside the object, it also can bring the documentation outside too, but it wouldn't do that a second ago, before putting the property in that object

[image: 2022-Rider JSDoc Extended Type usage, on specific property outside object and have the property inside object somewhere]

Image 5:

1. Again it mess it up when it come to sub property

[image: 2022-Rider JSDoc Extended Type usage, try listing sub-properties outside object and have the property inside object somewhere]

### Other extending methods

There are other extending methods people mentioned out there, and I tried, but didn't got deep in them:

I drop the module and change name to A and B for better understanding

Base

```js
/** @typedef A
 * @template T
 * @property ...
   ...       ...
   ...       ...
 */
```

1. Currently explained

```js
/**
 * @typedef B
 * @extends {A<MyType>}
 */
```

2. 

```js
/**
 * @typedef {A<MyType>} B
 */
```

3. 

```js
/**
 * @typedef B
 * @type {A<MyType>}
 */
```

4. **NOTE:** the article I found used the object with small `o`, but rider gave me error so I changed it to Capital `O`

```js
/**
 * @typedef B
 * @type {Object.<A<MyType>>}
 */
```

### Conclusion

It's seem to be best to re-define all the types but do not rely on JSDoc extends as no IDE creator gives it much of credit to go that deep, even different IDE have their own preferences, for example some do this: `@property {type} x - description` other do `@property x {type} description`, and so on, and there is no strong contract between them when they are parsing this language