# Import jsdoc type hint with template type

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a type definition with template T in module *render.js*

```js
/**
 * @typedef {(item:T) => String} ItemRenderer<T>
 */

/**
 * Render thing
 * @param {T} item thing to render
 * @returns {String} rendered thing
 */
export function render (item) {
  return item.toString()
}
```

This type is then imported in another module (let's call it *thing-list.js*)

```js
import { render } from './render.js'

/**
 * @typedef {import('./render.js'.ItemRenderer<T>)} ItemRenderer<T>
 */

/**
 * @returns {ItemRenderer<Thing>} renderer
function getRenderer () {
  return render
}

/**
 * List Things
 * @param {Thing[]} list list of things
 * @param {ItemRenderer<Thing>} render function
 * @returns {String[]} rendered list
 */ 
function listThings(list, render) {
  return list.map(render)
}

listThings(list, getRenderer())
```

In VSCode the above resolves the types up until the first `ItemRenderer<T>` in *thing-list.js*. After that I get `any /* unresolved */`. This method - importing type definitions - does work well for all other types so far. This is the first one to use a template.
I tried to dumb down the example as much as possible this is why it is not very practical as such. It's only to highlight the concept of an imported type definition with a template.

Does anyone here know if this can work with JSDoc type hints (in VSCode) at all or if I am doing something wrong?

-- UPDATE

The answers in [jsdoc: extend type with template (extend type with generic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591826/jsdoc-extend-type-with-template-extend-type-with-generic) look promising.

So I tried a definition with a @template

```
/**
 * @typedef {(item:T, indent:String, last:Boolean, level:Number) => String} TreeItemRenderer<T>
 * @template T
 */
```

Which changes the output but still the second ItemRenderer does not resolve :/

Answer (score 0):

OK, this @template T is needed

```js
/**
 * @typedef {(item:T, indent:String, last:Boolean, level:Number) => String} TreeItemRenderer<T>
 * @template T
 */
```

but the actual problem was the placement of the closing parentheses in the import statement. Why it does not say it's wrong but somehow resolves to a type is beyond me.

```js
/**
 * @typedef {import('./render.js').ItemRenderer<T>} ItemRenderer<T>
 */
```